# Redirect undefined subdomains to main domain in nginx?

Tags: redirect, nginx, subdomain

I want to redirect undefined subdomains to my main domain.
So I have a site domain.com and i have 2 subdomains: sub1.domain.com and sub2.domain.com.
And what I want is that when someone tries to go to sub4.domain.com that it mismatches in nginx and redirects it to domian.com. Can this be achieved?

Answer (score 1):

This will redirect any subdomain request.
For all existing subdomains you have to add `server` entry.

```
# this will catch all subdomains and redirect to main domain.
server {
  server_name *.domain.com;
  return 301 http://domain.com$request_uri;
}

# this block will be used for sub1.domain.com;
server {
  server_name sub1.domain.com;
  ...
}

# this is for sub2.domain.com;
server {
  server_name sub2.domain.com;
  ...
}

# and so on...
```

nginx has no idea of which subdomains exists and which are not. So you have to explicitly name all of them.

Comment: that's not exactly what I want. I want to redirect subdomains that do not exist yet. so sub1.domain.com exists en sub2.domain.com exists but sub3.domain.com does not exist yet or sub4.domain.com and what I want is that those 2, sub3 and sub4, get redirected to domain.com. Is that possible?

Comment: What does "not exist subdomain" means for you? If there is no DNS record for `sub4.domain.com` there is no way to add redirect, so I assume you have your DNS to provide some IP for that domain.

Comment: I have  a DNS record for sub4.domain.com and I want it to redirect to the domain.com. What non existant means to me is that it is not defined anywhere in nginx.